# How do I set order by field when using fuelphp orm's has many?

Tags: orm, has-many, fuelphp

I'm using fuelphp's orm to model my data.  How can I control which order my child elements are returned when doing a cascaded find.

For example, here's the example config to attach comments to a post:

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
    'comments' => array(
        'key_from' => 'id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Comment',
        'key_to' => 'post_id',
        'cascade_save' => true,
        'cascade_delete' => false,
    )
);
```

How can I say, for example, order the comments by the 'date_entered' field?

Thanks in advance,
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the order_by clause to the conditions.

```
protected static $_has_many = array(
    'comments' => array(
        'key_from' => 'id',
        'model_to' => 'Model_Comment',
        'key_to' => 'post_id',
        'cascade_save' => true,
        'cascade_delete' => false,
        'conditions' => array(
            'order_by' => array(
                'field1' => 'DESC',
                'field2' => 'ASC',
            )
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that as they are defined in the relation, they are always active and can not be turned off!